# inheritance question, affecting child class directly to parent class without pointers

Tags: c++

Ok so i'm trying a few things with inheritance, heres the code:

```
class A {
protected:
    int i;
public:
    A() :i(0) {}
    A(int n):i(n) {}
};

class B :public A {
public:
    B() :A() { }
    B(int n):A(n) { }

};
```

I know that you can affect a pointer to parent with a pointer to child, and i understand why:

```
B* b = new B();
A *a(0);
a = b;
```

[image]

But i also found out that you can do this:

```
A ac = *b;
```

or

```
A &ac = *b;
```

But isnt it literally affecting the object b to ac, instead of just pointer to memory location?

By the way, i'm not completely sure of what using & does in a declaration, I understand it as a default pass by reference.

Comment: Your C++ textbook should have a full explanation of what `&` does in a declaration statement, is there something in your textbook's description that's unclear to you?

Comment: The first one copies the `A` subobject from `*b` into `ac`. The second one is similar to `A *ac = n;`, `&` designates a "reference".

Comment: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/references/

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to understand that C++ does not always protect you to do wrong things. Just because you can write some code that does not trigger a compiler error does not mean that it is correct and meaningful code.

In general `A ac = *b;` is wrong when `A` is a base class of `b`. `*b` is a `B` and assigning that to an `A` will slice all members of `B`. In your example `B` has no additional members, but in general [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) is bad and one needs to take care of that.

On the other hand, this

```
A& ac = *b;
```

is fine always, because `ac` is just a reference to an `A`. It is similar to

```
A* ap = b;
```

as you can only use `A`s interface on `ac`. No copy is made here and the actual object (referenced by `ac`) is still a `B`.

---

> By the way, i'm not completely sure of what using & does in a declaration, I understand it as a default pass by reference.

The symbol `&` has different meanings depending on context. In `A& ac = *b;` it is part of the type: reference to `A`. This is the same as when passing an argument by reference to a function. You only need to consider a quirk in the grammar, that makes `A& ac=*b, ac2;` declare one `A&` called `ac` and one `A` called `ac2`. It is best to declare only one variable per line.